# How to make browsers automatically format numbers by setting their lang in html?

Tags: html, css, tags, lang

Is this possible to add some tags or write some CSS code to make browsers render something like this html code:

```
<div lang="fa">1 2 3 4 5 6</div>
```

to this:

```
۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ ۵ ۶
```

?

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is not achievable with CSS rather with JS or HTML

Answer (score 1):

Here I used Unicode shift since numerals in any Unicode group are placed in the same order as in Latin group (i.e. [0x0030 ... 0x0039]). So, for example, for Arabic-Indic group shift is 0x0630. [unicode codepros](http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)
I hope this is you want.

```js
$("[lang='fa']").text(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/\d/g, function(v) {
        return String.fromCharCode(v.charCodeAt(0) + 0x0630);
    });
});
```

```css
div {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div lang="fa">0123456789</div>
```

Comment: It's a good solution for static (or maybe some simple dynamic) pages but is not enough for a web application in which contents update asynchronously or for inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not reachable by pure `HTML/CSS`. 
You can write a script that get all `divs` by selector and change locale according to the `attribute` on your dom-node.

On the example output will be `"١٬٢٣٤"`.

`var number = 1234;
number.toLocaleString('ar-EG');`